# Possible to directly bind Ember template elements' class attribute based on boolean expression?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want to set a css class on a div enclosing a template control based on whether the model's particular field has errors on it. I know I can create boolean properties on the controller and set/unset them. But I don't want to do that for a number of reasons.

So I want something like this:

```
<div {{bindAttr class="(errors.email != undefined):error"}}>
  {{view Ember.TextField placeholder="Email" valueBinding="email" required=true}}
</div>
```

OR

```
<div class="{{(errors.email != undefined ? 'error' : '')}}">
  {{view Ember.TextField placeholder="Email" valueBinding="email" required=true}}
</div>
```

I feel something like this has to be possible in Ember!

UPDATE:

Snap! Right after posting, I realized I can do an {{#if}}. Will post solution for those interested later. Very basic stuff. I hope.

UPDATE 2:

Doesn't look like it's possible to have boolean expressions in the conditionals (e.g.  {{#if}} or {{#unless}} ) either. But in my case, I can just check if errors.emails is *truthy*:

```
{{#if errors.email}}
  <div class="control-group error">
{{/if}}
{{view Ember.TextField placeholder="Email" valueBinding="email" required=true}}
{{#if errors.email}}
  </div>
{{/if}}
```

Not pretty, but you'd expect it to work. And yet, it doesn't render as I'd expect. Instead of wrapping the TextField in the div when there are email errors, the div opens and closes before the TextField control. Here's how it's rendered:

```
<div class="error">
  <script id="metamorph-21-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
</div>
<input class="ember-view ember-text-field" placeholder="Email" type="text" required="required">
```

I guess I can put the TextField in the {{#if}} and the {{else}}, but it's getting uglier and uglier by the minute. Any suggestions to prettify would be appreciated.

Here's how I'm doing it now:

```
{{#if errors.email}}
    <div class="control-group error">
        {{view Ember.TextField placeholder="Email" valueBinding="name"}}
        <span class="help-inline">{{errors.email}}</span>
    </div>
{{else}}
    {{view Ember.TextField placeholder="Email" valueBinding="email" required=true}}
    <label class="required">* required</label>
{{/if}}
```

It works, and looks nice in the browser. But I know I'll have to refactor it into something more DRY at some point. Can't be creating these 8-line blocks for each validated field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom `View` with `classNameBindings`. For boolean attributes Ember Views toggle application of the class to the element.

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
  classNameBindings: ['hasError:error'],
  error: false,
  hasError: function() {
    return !Ember.isEmpty(this.get('error'));
  }.property('error')
});
```

Then you can use the view in handlebars like,

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='application'>
  {{view App.MyView error=errors.email}}
</script>
```

The `error` class will be added if the model `errors.email` is present.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking to set individual control styles based on their respective bound field errors, if any. If I wanted to do view-level, it would be very straight forward with a controller property, sort of how you're doing it. But I don't want to go that route because it gets messy fast with multiple controls.